# Windows 7 "phantom" window - JDialog

Tags: java, windows, swing

I'm experiencing weird issue with the simplest Java application (tested with JDK6 , JDK 8) running in Windows 7 (32 bit, service pack 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final JFrame frame = new JFrame();        
  Button b = new Button("show popup");
  b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {            
      JDialog  d = new JDialog(frame);
      d.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE); // default
      // d.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      d.add(new JTextField("Hello everybody. I'm phantom dialog!!!"));
      d.setBounds(20, 20, 300, 100);
      d.setVisible(true);
    }
  });       
  frame.add(b);
  frame.setBounds(30, 30, 600, 400);
  frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

The scenario:

1. run the application,
2. click the button (JDialog is opened),
3. Close the JDialog but keep the application running,
4. See application preview in the taskbar (see attached screenshot):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk9h4.png]

Note, that Windows displays the JDialog even though it was closed in step 3. I know that 
HIDE_ON_CLOSE option means that setVisible(false) is called when JDialog is closed but the question is:
Why, in taskbar preview, Windows renders JDialog that was closed?

Comment: I don't understand your question. When you hover the mouse over the frame icon in the task bar all that is displayed is a small image of the frame. That is what I see in your image and when I run the code.

Comment: Huh... It's the same here using Windows 10. 1) Why use a `Button` instead of `JButton`? 2) Why use `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` rather than `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` (which makes the phantom dialog disappear)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. 1/ the button X jbutton is not important here, I wrote quick sample to demonstrate the issue. Hide on close is default value, of course I can call dispose every time. The question is not about how to solve the issue. It’s about why it happens.

Comment: @camickr when the image of the frame appears, hover over that image. Then you'll see.

Comment: @JosefVeselý, no I don't see the problem. I'm using JDK 8 on Windows 7. `I wrote quick sample to demonstrate the issue.` - well the sample should be the code you want to use in your application not some random code. We don't have time to speculate when you use incorrect code.  `It’s about why it happens` - it is a platform difference and we would have no idea why it is different. Try Andrew's suggestions to see if it helps.

Comment: @camick Sorry but I don't agree, I think the sample should be simple piece of code that demonstrates the issue and can be easily used by whoever wants to investigate the issue (which this does with both JButton, Button or whatever widget that serves the purpose). Another thing is that very often you cannot share the code you want to use because it's property of your employer (which this case is also).

Comment: @JosefVeselý  `I think the sample should be simple piece of code that demonstrates the issue` - agreed. However we should be confident that you haven't made a silly mistake. I have seen many cause where the problem is a result of a typo. As you have seen from my comment this appears to be a LAF issue. Well it COULD have been caused by using an AWT component instead of a Swing component. Not using a JButton is sloppy. Give us confidence you have done proper testing and you have eliminated this possibility.

Comment: `often you cannot share the code you want to use because it's property of your employer` - agreed. We never want to see you actual application code. We want it simplified to the bare essentials that demonstrates the problem, which you have done, except for using a Button instead of a JButton. I agree it is unlikely to be the cause of THIS problem, but you never know in the future when it will make a difference.